# How to Enable/Disabled cron using command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

Is there any command that can switch ENABLE/DISABLE cron job in Ubuntu?

This command can disable a perticular cron which you want to commendt out

```
 - some\/job.sh

crontab -l | sed "/^[^#].* \/some\/job.sh/s/^/#/" | crontab -
```

If i run this bove comment the only one cron can stop means

This command can put **#** in starting of cron.(DISABLED)

can any one tell me how to remove this # 
(ENABLE) cron using command.

Comment: any one help me??